# alt+tab, alt+`, show titles, switching between, open windows, example using Chrome

Tags: unity, 16.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

**Context**

- In Windows 10, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between **[all open windows]**
- In Ubuntu 16.04, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between **[all open applications (window groups) - and not all windows]** (has a very long delay to switch between windows within an app) -- and you cannot see all the open windows like you can in win10
- In Ubuntu 16.04, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between **[all open windows IN THE CURRENT APPLICATION]**

---

**Goal is to create a better, easier workflow**

So when you have Chrome up in Ubuntu 16.04,

- when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> -- **how do you show the title of all of the windows like it does in win10?** and im assuming something similar in macOS
- how do you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any easy shortcut to SEE all open windows, and switch between **[all open windows]**
- how do you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between **[all open windows - that are NOT minimised]?**

---

**Possible solution**

- workspaces can be a possible solution IF it's easy to open chrome windows in different workspaces, and if workspaces reaches the goal presented
- please suggest any and all other possible solutions -- that are good

---

**Higher goal**

- I'm testing a fully installed Ubuntu on a different laptop, I'm very surprised that Ubuntu has these basic limits and it's **incredibly difficult** to locate the relevant/helpful info via the extremely 1) unorganised, and 2) excessive mess of google & spammy commercial websites
- So I finally gave up and decided to try asking (since highly experienced people are the single best source for any kind of information)

Comment: the usage of 'best' is not in the questions. the usage is additional and part of the context i want to provide. if the community is bad (i dunno) then the system overall needs to be fixed. i dont think anyone would mis-interpret the post by conflating the questions and the context inappropriately. -- anyhow, the logistics/administrative is a large cost/burden of asking a simple question, and makes communicating a question overall not worthwhile honestly, but hey google is much worst so i can deal with it..

Comment: What's your question? This looks like a bug report or design proposal.

Comment: Nice feature request. Please post it in appropriate forum

Answer (score 4):

> in ubuntu 16.04, alt+tab switches between [all open applications (window groups) - and not all windows] (has a very long delay to switch between windows within an app) -- and you cannot see all the open windows like you can in win10

The delay can be avoided if you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> once you've positioned the highlight of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  on the appropriate window group. For instance, you switch over to chrome group and immediately initiate switching with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> . On most keyboards <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> are close so I won't buy an excuse that those keys are too far to reach or it's two keys to type - people spend far more keystrokes on useless stuff ( like this sentence).

> how do you use alt+tab or any easy shortcut to SEE all open windows, and switch between [all open windows]

Use <kbd>Super(aka Windows key)</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. This will open expo of all open windows. You can use either mouse or arrow keys to select the one you want.

All window titles cannot be shown in the expo,  only of the selected window. The way to get around this is to use mouse or arrow keys to highlight window, thus revealing its title.

> how do you use alt+tab or alt+` to switch between [all open windows - that are NOT minimised]?

That's not available. You can however put a feature request to Unity (which is the desktop name Ubuntu uses) developers.

> workspaces can be a possible solution IF it's easy to open chrome windows in different workspaces, and if workspaces reaches the goal presented

Yes, it's possible to do the same thing I described above ( <kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> ) but with workspaces the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. The rules here change however - you can only show all chrome windows with <kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, but switching between them is still <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>

> I'm very surprised that ubuntu has these basic limits

If you're using Windows as standard - sure , these might seem as limits. Look at Ubuntu's work flow from a different perspective. You already figured out there's switcher for window groups. This is useful when you have tons of applications open - you don't want to switch between 35 windows just to reach the one you want. Got the Chrome group ? Got your window ? boom - done. So instead of looking at these as limitations, think of this as different standards.

Comment: computing should work for the user's needs, not us being slaves to technology. this is a lot to consider -- but the first most important blockage is it **absolutely** needs to **show the window titles**. i've no idea what's in these windows. i think gnome doesn't have this limit, but i heard unity was better in other ways, plus it's default, so it has to have basics right. im pretty sure macos doesnt have this limit but can't fully confirm via images -- this is a huge failure in basic UX, and that OSs have generally not kept pace with the chrome frontier. hmm.. wonder how chromebook does it..

Comment: `computing should work for the user's needs, not us being slaves to technology.` You forget that each user is different and their needs are different. I hope you can understand my respectful disagreement that shoving everything into the same mold doesn't do anything good for users - it creates monopoly for any single company. As for window titles, I could agree that this is useful feature and you can request feature request on Launchpad from Unity developers.

Comment: well i don't know what to say about this. google chrome team knows about the many power users that have lots of tabs open in multiple chrome windows, and i've no idea how anyone can **live** with this kind of UI. i'll definitely make a note to find out how macos does it, this is unbelievable, windows which controls like ~80% of the world or something i think had this since forever, it's such a basic thing in life -- alt+tab -- i was wrong, it's 90% -- http://www.extremetech.com/computing/227693-windows-drops-below-90-market-share-for-the-first-time-in-years-windows-7-falls-below-50

Comment: [8.16] el capitan has it -- http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245484/alt-tabbing-through-windows

Comment: Instead of Super-W, I use hot-corner in scale plugin of CCSM. You can't have them in Windows. It's super easy.